# Google Webmaster Tools: "There was an error parsing your JSON-LD."

Tags: google-search-console, json-ld

I have just logged into Google Webmaster Tools and am finding an error in structured data relating to a new WordPress theme I am using:

> JSON-LD: There was an error parsing your JSON-LD.

The code it is referring to is:

```html
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Townsville Nerds - Ph 0402 807 890" />
<script type='application/ld+json'>
    execOnReady(function({{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"WebSite","url":"http:\/\/www.townsvillenerds.com\/","name":"Townsville Nerds - Ph 0402 807 890"}})
</script>
```

NOTE: In Webmaster Tools there is a red underscore under the "e" in the word "execOnReady".

Answer (score 2):

Your data block does not contain valid JSON-LD (`application/ld+json`).

Instead of

```html
<script type='application/ld+json'>
    execOnReady(function({{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"WebSite","url":"http:\/\/www.townsvillenerds.com\/","name":"Townsville Nerds - Ph 0402 807 890"}})
</script>
```

it should be

```html
<script type='application/ld+json'>
    {"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"WebSite","url":"http:\/\/www.townsvillenerds.com\/","name":"Townsville Nerds - Ph 0402 807 890"}
</script>
```

I guess you don’t need to escape the `/`, so it could be:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
     "@context": "http://schema.org",
     "@type": "WebSite",
     "url": "http://www.townsvillenerds.com/",
     "name": "Townsville Nerds - Ph 0402 807 890"
    }
</script>
```